Navigation menu items visibility in Bulma CSS on mobile
I'm using Bulma css without any Javascript or other styles, directly imported in my html.
I am trying to change the display options for the navigation menu to show my call-to-action buttons in the mobile as well as on desktop. By default Bulma attempts to put these items into a hamburger menu, I want to disable this and keep the buttons as is or resize them if needed to fit better. IE, they remain right aligned and the logo remains left aligned on desktop and mobile.
My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Cntrl_Frk/xe580a4w/19/
I've tried setting the display type to flex on areas here and am not getting it to reflow into the nav correctly:
        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-light">CTA1 </a>
                <a class="button is-primary"> CTA2 </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

